# need to display timestamp in UTC as some other timezone and not browser locale in highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, timezone

in the chart, i do not want to display the time in my local timezone, the timestamps are in UTC but it seems, highchart is displaying it in browser locale timezone. I just need to display this UTC timestamp in America/Edmonton. Please help. The options that I have is with setting timezone property in highchart but i already have in UTC, just want to display differently.

```
time: {
            timezone:'America/Edmonton',
            moment,
          },
```

also i saw we can add globalOptions with the same timezone property.. but how to do that in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts should be able to find the `moment` library when loading as an import. You need to add under import `window.moment = moment;`, because `moment` is not in the window.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import MomentTimeZone from 'moment-timezone'
import Moment from 'moment'

MomentTimeZone();
Moment();

window.moment = Moment;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-glda29?file=index.js

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Time